# How to fast switch co concrete application window (in Windows 7 and KDE)

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, kde

I am wondering if there is a built-in support for fast switching between application windows in `Windows 7` and `KDE` based on the application name or if there is software which can does this.

What I would like to have is something similar to `Alt + F2` in KDE or `Windows key` functionality when you can quickly run an application. But instead running a new instance, just switching to existing instance:

1.pressing a key would display input box

2.writing into input box would display the matching results for currently opened windows and
after pressing enter I would be able to chose application which I want to bring to top

Answer (score 0):

There are many keyboard shortcut tools that will quickly launch a favorite application or just activate (bring to front ) it, if it is running in the background.

For example, I have used AutoHotKey in Windows for just this purpose and [at the ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=766596) there is a discussion about Linux alternatives.

Hope that helps.